# Вложенный цикл выполняется только один раз

Tags: c++, циклы

Дан массив. Выведите те его элементы, которые встречаются в массиве только один раз. Элементы нужно выводить в том порядке, в котором они встречаются в списке. 
Есть код, но в нем вложенный цикл выполняется только один раз, то есть выводит только первый элемент, если он уникальный.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, count = 0, k = 0;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        for (int k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            if (a[i] == a[k] && i != k) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
            else continue;
         }
        if (count == 0) {
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
        else continue;

    }
        return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    count = 0;
    // ...
}
```

count надо обнулять в начале каждого цикла.

А также: `else continue` прямо перед завершением цикла `}` ничего не дает, просто лишний шум.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)